# Unity View is coming on top of current view

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine

I am trying to integrate the Unity build for iOS into a pre-existing native app. I am using two buttons to start and stop the unity, but when I click on start, Unity view comes on the top of the current view and both the buttons disappear behind it. I used Unity 2019.1.11f1 for building the unity project.

Below is my App Delegate Code:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  blue
//
//  Created by Vikas Roy on 01/07/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 MedleyOne. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var application: UIApplication?

    @objc var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!

    var isUnityRunning = false


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.application = application

        unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

        currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
        currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.

        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application)
        }

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
        }

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillEnterForeground(application)
        }

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
        }

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func startUnity() {
        if !isUnityRunning
        {
            isUnityRunning = true
            currentUnityController.applicationDidBecomeActive(application!)
        }
    }

    func stopUnity() {
        if isUnityRunning {
            currentUnityController.applicationWillResignActive(application!)
            isUnityRunning = false
        }
    }


}
```

Below is the View Controller Code:

```
//
//  Unity3DViewController.swift
//  blue
//
//  Created by Vikas Roy on 25/07/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 MedleyOne. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class Unity3DViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func showUnitySubView() {
        if let unityView = UnityGetGLView() {
            view?.insertSubview(unityView, at: 0)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func StartUnity(_ sender: Any) {

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        {
            appDelegate.startUnity()
            showUnitySubView()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func StopUnity(_ sender: Any) {

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        {
            appDelegate.stopUnity()

        }

    }

}
```

I want buttons to always stay on the top of the unity view. Any idea where the issue can be?

Comment: I don't think you can. Unity is designed to run full screen all the time every time and does not have a native concept of transparency.

Comment: Actually, I am working on a legacy project. It has got unity embedded in the native app. The native app fully controls the unity. What I am trying to do right now is make some changes in unity and re integrate it in the app.

Comment: Beats me. I've only tried to do something similar on Android once and was never able to get that kind of effect, so props to the guy that *did* manage it, but he's probably the only one that knows how.

Comment: I am following this article https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82. He also seems to have control over unity.

Answer (score 1):

In `ViewContoller`, where `Unity` is loading, 
create an outlet of your button 
and call this function in `viewDidload()` this way:

```
let unityView = UnityGetGLView()
unityView.addsubView(yourbutton)
```